# How to float a div vertical center aligned in another div

Tags: html, css

I have a slideshow. I also have a previous and next button.
The slideshow re-sizes according to the screen size it is displayed on.
I need the previous and next button to always be in the center of the slide show.
If I add `position: absolute;` it does not look right on bigger screens.

html:

```
<div class="slideshow" style="position: relative;">
    </div>
    <div id="prev"></div>
    <div id="next"></div>
```

css:

```
#prev, #next
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    width: 41px;
    height: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 300px;
}

#prev
{
    left: 0;
    background-image: url("img/prev.png");
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#next
{
    right: 0;
    background-image: url("img/next.png");
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to set top: 50% ?

Comment: Hello @Beginner please show more code ......

Comment: yes i have set it to 50% but it does 50% of page not the slideshow div

Comment: This is because your slideshow doesn't have height

Comment: yeh the height gets set dynamically if the user resizes the screen etc

Comment: And how the slideshow height is set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="prev"></div>
<div id="next"></div>
```

These should be inside

```
<div class="slideshow" style="position: relative;">
</div>
```

and then inside css

```
#prev, #next{position:absolute;top:50%}
```

I hope it will fix your issue

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming the slideshow is full screen as the prev/next elements are outside the slideshow.

http://jsfiddle.net/kudoslabs/aFJze/

you need to position the top to 50% and offset the height of the anchors.

```
#prev, #next{
top: 50%;
margin-top: -20px ; /*half the height of the element, assuming 40px*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As i see it not positioning correctly because

```
    <div id="prev"></div>
   <div id="next"></div>
```

Doesnt have a wrapper what has a position relative, i see the slideshow has it, place it inside and position it should be fine

this

```
<div class="slideshow" style="position: relative;">
    </div>
    <div id="prev"></div>
    <div id="next"></div>
```

to this

```
<div class="slideshow" style="position: relative;">
    <div id="prev"></div>
    <div id="next"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i will give this a go, if i have the browser on say a 27 inch screen and have top set to 300px which looks centered in my screen, will it look centered in the bigger screen

Comment: yes, coz when you make and absolute position you need to wrapp it with a wrapper what has a relative position, so if the wrapper element what has the relative changes the apsolute will stay just as you want

Comment: what if i needed something 10% from the bottom of the slideshow i would do the same?

Answer (score 0):

try this, you should adjust the css a bit , specifically margin-left to make them look side by side properly

Demo [Demo](http://jsbin.com/ukasek/1/edit)

```
#prev
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    width: 41px;
    height: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 50%;
    left : 50%;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:-40px;
} 

#next
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    width: 41px;
    height: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 50%;
    left : 50%;
    margin-left:-60px;
    margin-top:-40px;
}
```

Comment: i need them centred vertically not horizontally

Comment: did you took a look at the demo. Its centered both vertically and horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

i hope you are looking like this :- [DEMO](http://tinkerbin.com/Qr5a6Pl5)

**HTML**

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div id="prev"></div>
    <div id="next"></div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#slideshow {
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#prev, #next
{
    position: absolute;
    width:70px;
    height: 70px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;


}

#prev
{
    left:50%;
    background-image: url("http://www.mouserunner.net/free_games/Right_Arrow_Icon_Black.png");
}

#next
{
    right:50%;
    background-image: url("http://www.mouserunner.net/free_games/Right_Arrow_Icon_Black.png");
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```